# Monte Carlo method and structs

Tags: c

I've been assigned to make a program that deals 7-card hands and evaluates the probability that a hand has no pair, one pair, two pair, three of a kind, full house and 4 of a kind. The shuffle function works fine i've tested it separately. I've started from evaluating probability of a one pair first. in Monte Carlo method the probability is calculated by number of successfull trials divided by all trials. But the number of successfull trials (int c) comes out bigger than the number of all trials(int N). How is that possible? The outcome should be close to 0.43822546, bit gives out about 13 to 15 thousand (for 1000 trials). Maybe it has to do something with struct vars?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define SIZE 52
typedef enum { diamonds, hearts, clubs, spades }suit;
typedef enum { ace, jack, queen, king }honour;
typedef struct
{
    suit suit_card;
    honour honour_card;
    short pips_card;
}card;
void swap(card* a, card* b)
{
    card temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void printArray(card arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d %d//", arr[i].suit_card, arr[i].pips_card);
    printf("\n");
}
void shuffle(card arr[], int n)//function that generates random permutation of arr[](Fisher-yates algorithm)
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) //we start from the last element, swap one by one
    {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);//random index from 0 to i
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);//swap arr[i] with element at random index                                                       
    }
}
void approx_to_prob_onePair(card arr[],int n)
{
    int N = 0;
    int c = 0, d=0;
    printf("Enter number of hands for sampling:");// enter 1 000 000
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) 
    {
        shuffle(arr, SIZE);
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) 
        {
            for (int k = j+1; k < 7; k++) 
            {
                if (arr[j].pips_card == arr[k].pips_card||arr[j].honour_card == arr[k].honour_card)
                {
                    c+=1;
                }
                
            }
            
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n", c);
    double approxProb = c / N;
    printf("%.9fl", approxProb);
}

int main()
{
    card c1 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 2 };
    card c2 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 3 };
    card c3 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 4 };
    card c4 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 5 };
    card c5 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 6 };
    card c6 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 7 };
    card c7 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 8 };
    card c8 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 9 };
    card c9 = { .suit_card = hearts, .pips_card = 10 };
    card c10 = { .suit_card = hearts, .honour_card = ace };
    card c11 = { .suit_card = hearts, .honour_card = jack };
    card c12 = { .suit_card = hearts, .honour_card = queen };
    card c13 = { .suit_card = hearts, .honour_card = king };
    card c14 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 2 };
    card c15 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 3 };
    card c16 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 4 };
    card c17 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 5 };
    card c18 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 6 };
    card c19 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 7 };
    card c20 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 8 };
    card c21 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 9 };
    card c22 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .pips_card = 10 };
    card c23 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .honour_card = ace };
    card c24 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .honour_card = jack };
    card c25 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .honour_card = queen };
    card c26 = { .suit_card = diamonds, .honour_card = king };
    card c27 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 2 };
    card c28 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 3 };
    card c29 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 4 };
    card c30 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 5 };
    card c31 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 6 };
    card c32 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 7 };
    card c33 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 8 };
    card c34 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 9 };
    card c35 = { .suit_card = clubs, .pips_card = 10 };
    card c36 = { .suit_card = clubs, .honour_card = ace };
    card c37 = { .suit_card = clubs, .honour_card = jack };
    card c38 = { .suit_card = clubs, .honour_card = queen };
    card c39 = { .suit_card = clubs, .honour_card = king };
    card c40 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 2 };
    card c41 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 3 };
    card c42 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 4 };
    card c43 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 5 };
    card c44 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 6 };
    card c45 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 7 };
    card c46 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 8 };
    card c47 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 9 };
    card c48 = { .suit_card = spades, .pips_card = 10 };
    card c49 = { .suit_card = spades, .honour_card = ace };
    card c50 = { .suit_card = spades, .honour_card = jack };
    card c51 = { .suit_card = spades, .honour_card = queen };
    card c52 = { .suit_card = spades, .honour_card = king };
    card cardarray[] = {c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40,c41,c42,c43,c44,c45,c46,c47,c48,c49,c50,c51,c52};
    approx_to_prob_onePair(cardarray, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger to see *when* `c` is being incremented.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: OT: Please note that `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` must be done *before* you include any headers.

Comment: And call `srand` only ***once*** (unless you want to set the seed to exactly the same value multiple times). Preferably very early in the `main` function.

Comment: And don't include `<conio.h>`. It's a nonstandard header file left over from the old DOS days, and as far as I can see you don't use anything it declares or defines.

Comment: dividing an integer with another integer gives you integer division even if the resulting variable is a double `double approxProb = c / N;` that is probably not what you want.